# As a nagaji, what are my starting languages in PFS?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, languages, pathfinder-society

I've created a nagaji character for Pathfinder Society and I'm trying to figure out what languages I start with. There seems to be competing information in different sourcebooks, and PFS documentation doesn't appear to clear this up. The two sourcebooks that have nagaji are listed below with their entries.

Dragon Empires Gazetteer (page 10):

> **Languages:** Nagaji begin play speaking Nagaji and Tien. Nagaji with high intelligence scores can choose bonus languages from the following: any human tongue, Abyssal, Aklo, Celestial, Draconic, Giant, Infernal, Samsaran, Senzar, Sylvan, Tengu, and Wayang.

Advanced Race Guide (page 196):

> **Languages:** Nagaji begin play speaking Common and Draconic. Nagaji with high intelligence scores can choose bonus languages from the following: any human tongue, Abyssal, Aklo, Celestial, Draconic, Giant, Infernal, and Sylvan.

From this, it looks like there are two possible combinations of languages: (1) Nagaji and Tien or (2) Common and Draconic. What gets more confusing is that the bonus languages for both include Draconic, even though the ARG has Draconic as a starting language. I also found this from the Pathfinder Society Roleplaying Guild Guide for season 8 (page 25):

> **Kitsune, Nagaji, Tengu, or Wayang:** Kitsune, nagaji, tengu, and wayang characters who are from Tian Xia rather than Avistan or Garund can automatically speak both Tien and Common in addition to their racial languages.

So as a nagaji in PFS, assuming my region of origin is Tian Xia, what are my starting languages? I'm thinking it's Nagaji, Tien, and Common, but the ARG seems to indicate I should also have Draconic. What about if I'm not from Tian Xia?

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, [not posting small or incomplete answers](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6534). Please use answer posts to submit answers instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You get the languages that the source says you get.

[A topic on paizo.com messageboards](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2th11?Nagaji-starting-languages#1) came to the conclusion that the starting languages depends on what source you are using to build a nagaji character. (Even if the race is allowed, you still technically need to own the source material to use it.) Nagaji is something of a special case because it has many different, slightly varying sources available, unlike (say) elves.

If you use Dragon Empires Gazetteer as your source, your nagaji speaks Nagaji and Tien (and Common, because every PC in PFS automatically speaks Common).

If you use Advanced Race Guide as your source, your nagaji speaks Common and Draconic (and Tien, if your nagaji comes from Tian Xia). This leads to the slightly humorous incident that your nagaji doesn't speak Nagaji.

If you use Inner Sea Races as your source, your nagaji speaks Common and Nagaji (and Tien, if your nagaji comes from Tian Xia).